# DeclarationError: Undeclared identifier - although it's present in ERC721.sol

Tags: ethereum, solidity, truffle, openzeppelin

I am writing a contract on solidity 0.8.3 and I get this strange error for `_setTokenURI()` although the method is [defined in OpenZeppelin 4.X](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/4.x/api/token/erc721#ERC721URIStorage-_setTokenURI-uint256-string-).

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.3;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/ERC721.sol";
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract NFTB is ERC721 {

  using Counters for Counters.Counter;
  Counters.Counter private _tokenIds;
  mapping(string => uint8) hashes;

  constructor() public ERC721("NFTB", "NFTB") {}

  function awardItem(address recipient, string memory hash, string memory metadata) public returns (uint256) {
    require(hashes[hash] != 1);
    hashes[hash] = 1;
    _tokenIds.increment();
    uint256 newItemId = _tokenIds.current();
    _setTokenURI(newItemId, metadata);
    _mint(recipient, newItemId);
    return newItemId;
  } }
```

[image]

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Function `_setTokenURI()` is defined in `@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol` ([source on GitHub](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/v4.0.0/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol#L44)), but this contract is not imported by your code (including nested imports). That's why the function is undeclared.

Since `ERC721URIStorage` extends `ERC721`, you can extend your `NFTB` directly from `ERC721URIStorage`.

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC721/extensions/ERC721URIStorage.sol"; // changed import
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/utils/Counters.sol";

contract NFTB is ERC721URIStorage { // changed parent
```

Comment: When I make a few million $USD in the next month, I'll surely give you a donation.

Comment: I tried this as well but it is not working on my machine, still get undeclared. I'm using solidify 0.8.0

Comment: @jalapina be sure to update all references in your .sol of ERC721 to ERC721URIStorage